# In CustomLogoutSuccessHandler , The authentication object is always null

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am always getting null for Authentication object in my custom logoutSuccesshandler, I am not sure what is the issue. :(

Here is the spring-security file:

```
    <sec:http auto-config="true" entry-point-ref="ssoProcessingFilterEntryPoint"
        access-decision-manager-ref="affirmativeBased">
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/afterAuthn/**" access="${spring.security.role}" />
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/tenancy/**" access="${spring.security.role}" />
        <!-- Add permissions to specific URLS - i.e. IAM.User.Read for /resources/** -->
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**"
            access="${default.permission}" />
        <sec:logout invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="true"
            success-handler-ref="customLogoutSuccessHandler" />
        <sec:custom-filter ref="ssoAuthenticationFilter"
            position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <sec:session-management>
            <sec:concurrency-control max-sessions="1" />
        </sec:session-management>
    </sec:http>
..
<bean id="customLogoutSuccessHandler"
        class="usermgmt.service.CustomLogoutSuccessHandler">
         <property name="defaultLogoutSuccessUrl" value="${service.provider.logout.success.url}"/>
    </bean>
```

My custom class handler:

```
public class CustomLogoutSuccessHandler implements LogoutSuccessHandler {
@Override
    public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (authentication == null) {
            System.out.println("NULL");
        } else {
            System.out.println("NOT NULL");
        }
}}
```

Over here, authentication is always NULL and Spring security version is 3.1.0.RELEASE

Comment: Isn't that proper behaviour? I mean, if the user has properly logged out himself, the authentication object should be null, because there is really nothing to show. If the authentication object is not null, that means you have to deauthenticate the user manually.

Comment: yes, It is the right behaviour, For reference you cah check this URL: http://javapointers.com/tutorial/spring-custom-logoutsuccesshandler-example/

Comment: I've digged a while in the code, and this is not as straightforward as we thought it is. Check the `LogoutFilter` class from Spring Security WEB. Look at the `doFilter()` method, and you will see, that the authentication object is obtained and then passed to the `logout()` method, and finally to your `LogoutSuccessHandler`. So that means, your SecurityContext gives you null instead of an authentication object (should not happen here). You can debug this method and find out why your Authentication is null.

Comment: When I tried URL sample,It is working absolutely fine but when I tried to integrate with my application then I am getting null value. So, I guess, Debug is the only option left. thanks.!

Comment: @Waheed And did you debug it? Was was the result? It would be nice if you share your findings...

Answer (score 1):

This may be because you have SecurityContextLogoutHandler configured in spring security. SecurityContextLogoutHandler clears security context thereby clearing authentication object. Your custom handler is called after SecurityContextLogoutHandler. In order to retain the authentication object, you will have to create custom SecurityContextLogoutHandler and have necessary logic there.

In this class, you have 2 options:

1. Either you can put the authentication object in request attribute that can be retrieved in your custom logout success handler
2. Or compute the URL in your custom SecurityContextLogoutHandler and set it as request attribute Retrieve it in your custom logout success handler and set as default target URL